# How do I stop Caja from closing when a drive is disconected?

Tags: linux-mint

Caja 1.6.2 on Mint 16. When the network goes down, the Caja manager connected to a remote server via SSHFS closes itself. I want to disable this behaviour. It should just turn gray or something until the network is back.

Comment: Not sure how that would be possible (not sure it isn't either). If you're using sshfs the actual filesystem mounted disappears as soon as you loose the network. Caja is probably set up to close instead of crashing.

Comment: My understanding is that Caja was based on Nautilus. On Ubuntu 10.04 with Nautilus, it would gray out on network failure and come back.